# String not matching, even though "patternString" is a substring of "text"

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to learn Java Regular Expression and is trying to match a smaller string against another string. Below is the code I have came up with.

```
String text = "this is the text to be searched for occurrences of the http://www.nba.com.";
    String patternString = "http://.*";
    Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile(patternString);
    Matcher m1 = p1.matcher(text);
    boolean doesItMatch = m1.matches();
    System.out.println(doesItMatch);
    System.out.println(m1.group());
```

I was expecting the `doesItMatch` to equal `true` and `m1.group()` to equal `http://nba.com.`. However, the IDE instead output

```
false
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Matcher.java:536)
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Matcher.java:496)
    at JTORegex.RegularExpression.main(RegularExpression.java:23)
Java Result: 1
```

How come the string `patternString` is not matching against the string `text`? `patternString` does exist within `text`. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`matches` matches the full String.  Use `find` for partial matches

```
boolean hasAMatch = m1.find();
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
boolean doesItMatch = m1.matches();
if (doesItMatch)
    System.out.println(m1.group());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
varname.find();
```

or instantiate it with boolean variable

```
boolean newvar = varname.find();
```